# How can I get the full path to a file in powershell without knowing its name?

Tags: powershell

I have a single file in a subdirectory. How can I get the full path to this file without knowing its name? Note, I know there will only ever be a single file in this directory.

Here's a MWE:

```
cd D:
mkdir directory1
cd directory1
mkdir directory2
cd directory2
notepad file.txt # save when prompted and close
cd ..
```

```
PS D:\directory1> ls


    Directory: D:\directory1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        20/11/2020     14:04                directory2


PS D:\directory1>
```

In bash I would do something like this:

```
$ my_file=$(ls directory2)
$ echo "$my_file"
```

In powershell I'm trying

```
# error
Set-Variable -name my_file -value (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath (get-item (ls dist))
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
# powershell
$my_file
```

```
D:\full\path\to\directory1\directory2\file.txt
```

Comment: `$my_file = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath .\path\to\root\folder -Recurse -File |% FullName`

Comment: @CiaranWelsh PoewrShell is very flexible with aliases, `$my_file=$(ls directory2)` would work :)

Comment: Hmm I think I was missing the leading `$`. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) is rarely needed; it is simpler to use direct assignment, but note that PowerShell, unlike Bash, uses the `$` sigil in this case too: `$my_file = ...` (note the `$` and that spaces are allowed around the `=`, as opposed to Bash's `my_file=...`)
- If you're only interested in full path *strings*, using [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) is simplest.

```
$my_file = Convert-Path directory2/*  # Note: could return an *array* of paths
```

By contrast, if you want file-info *objects* whose `.FullName` property you can later query, use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):

```
$my_file = Get-ChildItem directory2
```